# Incompatibility of Visual studio 2012 with windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I have installed Visual studio 2012 on windows 7 Ultimate. but every time I open it , I get the message that

```
 " visual studio 2012 is incompatible with this version of windows. For more information , Contact Microsoft."
```

As far as I know that Visual studio 2012 could be installed on windows 7. How can  I find the incompatibility problem?

Comment: make sure you have the Win7 Sp1 + all offered updates installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Incompatibility issue occur when windows 7 is least update but Visual studio 2012 is not update .
this link is helpful to solve your issue

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d70fa670-bbe9-439d-9f4d-f8b6f503f2d2/vs2012-incompatibility-issue-with-win-7-64bit?forum=vssetup